# how to store associative array php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I want to store result of a query as associative array. Below is my code that generates the query result below.

```
<?php

$include('config.php') //mysql connection file
$result = mysql_query("SELECT daystime.*, Sprinkler_ID FROM daystime, scheduler WHERE   daystime.id = scheduler.DaysTime_ID ORDER BY daystime.id, Sprinkler_ID") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

$data_array = array();
while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $key=$rs['id'];
    $value=$rs['Sprinkler_ID'];
    $data_array[$key] = [$value];
}

foreach ($data_array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key.'=>'.$value.'<br />';
}
?>
```

[image: the resuting table]

This gives me output as

```
 19=>Array
 20=>Array
 21=>Array
 27=>Array
 29=>Array
```

But I should get

```
 19 -> [4,5],
 20 -> [5], 
 21=>[4,6], 
 // and so on
```

Comment: Adding as array value: `$data_array[$key] = [$value];`. You should probably count if `id` is more than 1 then add their values to said array

Answer (score 3):

`$value` is an array, you can't use `echo` on arrays

Don't loop just do a `var_dump()`

```
$data_array = array();
while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data_array[$rs['id']][]=$rs['Sprinkler_ID'];
}
var_dump($data_array);//or print_r($data_array);
```

Comment: so what should I use can you please provide the correct statement then

Comment: now i get array(5) { [19]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } [20]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } [21]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "6" } [27]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } [29]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "6" } }  @meda

Comment: if `var_dump` is an option, you should also try `print_r`. it gives you less information about the datatypes an just prints the data.
@meda you override the array instead of appending the othe `$rs['Sprinkler_ID']`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$include('config.php') //mysql connection file
$result = mysql_query("SELECT daystime.*, Sprinkler_ID FROM daystime, scheduler WHERE   daystime.id = scheduler.DaysTime_ID ORDER BY daystime.id, Sprinkler_ID") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

$data_array = array();
while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $key=$rs['id'];
    $value=$rs['Sprinkler_ID'];
    $data_array[$key] = [$value];
}
$out = '';
$count = count($data_array);
$iter = 0;
foreach ($data_array as $key => $value)
{
    $out.= $key.'=>[';
    foreach ($value as $val) {
        $out.=$val.',';
    }
    $out = rtrim($out, ",");
    $out.= ']';
    if ($iter < ($count-1)) {
        $out.=',<br />';
    }
    $iter++;
}
echo $out;
```

You need an inner foreach loop to handle printing the array in $value as this is a multi dimensional array.  The preceding is an example of how it could look to produce the exact output you requested.   If you are looking for a dump of the values, then please use the var_dump solution provided by @meda.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code. The first is that `$value` is an array, the second is that this array only contains one item.

Try this:

```
$data_array = array();
while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $key=$rs['id'];
    $value=$rs['Sprinkler_ID'];
    $data_array[$key][] = $value;
}

foreach ($data_array as $key => $values)
{
    echo $key.'=> [';
    foreach($values as $value)
       echo $value . ',';
    echo ']<br />';
}
```